# I cant write an object if it has a 'conexion' type of data, i get java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java

I have been able to save in text files using the Serializable interface, but when I implemented a connection to a DDBB, and therefore, using a Conexion type fo data, it won't let me write it on a file, as it seems to be not serializable, but the whole class is already serializable. I am really lost here. as is not a class who is giving a java.io.NotSerializableException, but an attribute of a class which is serializable.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 14728980251747878L;
protected ArrayList<Arma> Armas;
protected ArrayList<Cliente> Clientes;
private Connection conexion; //this is the one who wont let me save
```

Comment: The `Connection` class does not implement the `Serializable` interface so it can't be serialized. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: The question is pretty obvious, how do I write a class that has Connection without writing the connection.

Comment: I don't want to write Connection bcz it has no sense, but it doesn't let me save everything else, and that's why I am seeking for an answer.

Comment: Annotate it as `@transient`?

Comment: fixed, thanks Zephyr

Answer (score 0):

Extend the connection class and make a new class like this  SerializableConnection extends Connection implements serializable.

Comment: And then? How do you (de)serialize the base class' private members?